# Is there an API event for when a teacher grades an assignment in the Google Classroom API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-api, google-classroom

I'm working on a (Node) JavaScript project and trying to create an application that automatically transfers grades (when finalized by a teacher) to eSchoolPlus. To do this, I ned to run an action using the eSchoolPlus API whenever a grade if finalized in Google Classroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately not.*

#### More Information:

According to the Google Classroom [documentation on push notifications](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications#types_of_feeds):

> Types of feeds
> The Classroom API currently offers three types of feed:
>
> - Each domain has a **roster changes for domain** feed, which exposes notifications when students and teachers join and leave courses in that domain.
> - Each course has a **roster changes for course** feed, which exposes notifications when students and teachers join and leave courses in that course.
> - Each course has a **course work changes for course** feed, which exposes notifications when any course work or student submission objects are created or modified in that course.

So at the moment, this is not possible.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for the Classroom API and that you would like to request they implement it. Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services.

The page to file a Feature Request for Google Classroom is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908).

#### Refernces:

- [Push notifications in the Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications)